# Grab a single digit out of a big mess of html

Tags: javascript, regex

I am grabbing a div from the document with :

```
var myTotal = window.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML;
```

which returns a big mess of HTML

```
<div id="foo"> 
<a href="bar" onclick='_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "The", "Total",])'>
<img src="foo.gif" alt="foo" height="22px;/" width="15px;"></a> 
</div> 
<a href="bar" onclick='_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "The", "Total",])'> 
MY TOTAL: 
<span style="font-size: 12px; color: #F3A428; font-weight:normal;"> 8 item(s) </span>
</a>
```

Can one of you expression wizards please show me how I can grab just the number in the span, in this example an 8 ?

Comment: will the returned content always be the same, like is MY TOTAL static, the span?, etc...

Comment: yes, everything but that # (8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try, just using innerText

```
window.document.getElementById('status').innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X9ffE/

Comment: I cant get innerText to work.. and that fiddle doesnt work for me either ?

Comment: looks like there are some compatibility issues across browsers, it works on Chrome for me. I think there is also a textContent property

Comment: Thanks I did not know that firefox required textContent

Answer (score 2):

Can you give the span an id and reference it directly?

If not, then this regex should return the number in the span: `/<span[^>]+>\s*(\d+)/`

I'm assuming that there is only ever one span in the div.

Comment: no.. well ... i was thinking that earlier but it would be a real pain to access that span so I was hoping to get an easier way out with regex and working with what I can currently grab

Comment: ok.. you inspired me to actually try and do that rather than just consider it and I found where that was printed right away.  Still getting lost in the MVC.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
var myTotal = window.document.getElementById('status').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML
myTotal = myTotal.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, without even getting the inner HTML it would be this:

```
var items = $("#status span").first().text();
items = parseInt(items, 10);
alert(items);   // 8
```

If you control the HTML, it would be advisable to put a unique ID on the span containing the result and then it's easier to retrieve and not dependent upon the structure around it or better yet, have it output into the page as a JS variable that you can just directly read and not have to deal with the presentation.

Seen in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UqcxS/

Comment: wish i could use jQuery but in this situation I cant.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery instead, it has a lot of functions that can help you find specific elements in your page. Also, you may want to add identification for your elements like class and id.